# Set a password for external hard disk without format it

Tags: hard-drive, password, format, ext4

My external hard disk is 1TB in size and nearly 900GB data on it. I want to set up a password without format it. Is it possible?
file format is ext4.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's possible.

That's called **ATA password**. You can either set it through your EFI/BIOS firmware, if it allows you to do so. Or you can use `hdparm` to set such a password.

I would recommend to use your *EFI firmware* if applicable because `hdparm` comes with a lot of warning that it can brik your disk. That's kind of scary, even it is unlikely to happen. That are just cautious and warn you of the worst.

So if you want to use `hdparm`, it's something like:

```
sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-set-passwd "Secret" /dev/sdx
```

That is to set a **user password** 'Secret'. This will let the *master password* as set by the manufacturer (and let anyone knowing it unlock the drive).

You can eventually also set a *master password*. But read documentation before to know the consequences.

A good read is [this admin-magazine.com article](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2014/19/Using-the-ATA-security-features-of-modern-hard-disks-and-SSDs)

**Note**: if the drive with the ATA password is plugged-in while booting, your EFI firmware should ask you for that password. If you plugged it in after booting, I don't know how it is dealt with by *ubuntu*, but you might have to unlock the drive by issuing another `hdparm` command from a terminal, like

```
sudo hdparm --security-unlock 'Secret' --user-master u /dev/sdx
```

if we use the same variable in our previous example.

**Another possibility** is to use *ext4* *built-in encryption*, but it only encrypts per directory. Meaning, if you have multiple top directory on your HDD, you will need a password for each directory, unless you move them under the same top root directory. More instruction in the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4#Using_file-based_encryption) on how to enable **ext4 encryption**. This works on new files, so you will have to move all your data to the new encrpyted directory, just to encrypt them.

Comment: @Leckose If you think this is the answer, please mark it as the accepted answer by ticking the mark. thanks.